# htaccess proper redirect with trailing slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

Good day!

I want to make proper redirect by htaccess, when there is GET request like this:

```
example.org/directory/page/
```

It should give example.org/page.php

My htaccess lets only redirect this kind of request

```
example.org/directory/page
```

I use this config

```
#remove extension
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
#remove directory
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Thank you for attention!

Comment: Why do you need `RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ /$1 [L]` rule when you want to serve `example.org/directory/page.php` ?

Comment: excuse, mistake, I edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorder your rules and tweak `.php` adding rule:

```
#remove directory
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ /$1 [L]

#remove extension
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```